# Java Array binary search - negative output, don't want to sort

Tags: java, arrays

I have been using the binarySearch method on an int[] array to find the offset of a specific int value but sometimes it works fine and other times it throws back a negative number.

In other questions it is suggested that I sort the array first, but I don't want to do this as the order they are in must be kept.

```
System.out.println("Index of last point: "+validFlag+" "+Arrays.binarySearch(validFlags,validFlag));
```

I find it odd that this works in some cases and not in others, in the case of the others I can assure you the int value is in the array!
Suggestions?

Here's some console output from the program:

```
Possible flags: 26317584
Current flag: 6
Index of last point: 6 -7
```

Comment: Um, you can't use binary search on an array that's not sorted. If you don't want to sort, you have to check elements one by one.

Comment: provide the sample values where it doesn't work and your full code.

Comment: Binary search works by first going to the median of the array, and saying okay the number im looking for is either more than or less than this number. If the search param is > than the median it does the same thing to the right half of the array and so on. The reason you are getting -1 is because it can't find it, because the algorithm requires a sorted array. The only way to search an unsorted array takes O(N) time so just use a for loop to look for it or the `.contains()` method

Comment: It's not just a suggestion that the array must be sorted.  It's a *requirement.*. Sort the array or give up on using binary search.

Answer (score 0):

using Arrays.sort() method you must really sort it first

if you want to just find the number you can use looping

```
  for(int i=0;i<values.length;++i)
  {  
      if(myNumber==values[i])
      {
        i=values.length;
        foundValue=true;
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The main criteria of binary search is that your array has to be sorted. So if you want to use `binarySearch` to find an element then you must provide a sorted array. And if you don't want to sort the array then you can use `linear search` instead